# How to make dropdown populated within form tag with different selected values in loop?

Tags: html, angular

I have an array of employees to which tests are assigned by Lead. When assigning tests, selected employee is assigned properly. while populating back, Lead can see which test is assigned to which employee.

When table is in form tag, EmployeeID is populated correct but its corresponding employee name is different.

If I take out table from form tag, it works perfectly fine.

Employee id and names are like <1, FName1>, <2, FName2>, <3, FName3>, <4, FName4>

```
<form class="cc">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let t of tests">
                        <td>
                            {{t.empid}}
                            <select *ngIf="t" id="assigned" name="assignedto" [(ngModel)]="t.empid" class="form-control">
                                <option *ngFor="let e of empids; let i = index" [value]="e.employeeid">
                                    {{e.employeename}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Result is as below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are binding the value of the select with the `t.empid` value. The result of this is that when you choose an option, its value, which is `e.employeeid`, gets set to `t.empid`.

You haven't shown any TypeScript code for that component, but you can try to add a one more property to the objects in the `tests` array, for example `val`. Then use it to bind with ngModel: `[(ngModel)]="t.val"`.

And one more suggestion - your code generates multiple `select` elements with the same ID, which is something you have to avoid. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) *"The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document".*  If you use the `id="assigned"` only for styling purposes, you could just add a class attribute.

Comment: Same code works perfectly fine if <form> tag is not there. Why its not working when code is within <form> tag?

Comment: Could you please share the TypeScript code, it will be really helpful for reproducing the issue.